# Jquery ajax request in with zend framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I make a jquery ajax request like so:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: '{user : 1234}',
            url: '../../mycontroller-ajax/sort',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        }
    );
```

however, in the controller/action part, I disable the view first

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
```

but if I echo the

```
$_POST['user']
```

It says that the index is not defined

Comment: `data: {user : 1234},` instead `data: '{user : 1234}',` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data : {
'user' : 1234
}
```

Will definately help but i guess you will also need to include :

```
dataType : 'json'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 data: {user : 1234},
```

instead of

```
data: '{user : 1234}',
```